# Unable to instantiate activity when using signed .apk

Tags: android

My app works fine if I use the unsigned .apk However, if I test it with the signed .apk (the one to be uploaded to Google Play) in device, it throw below error. Is this normal, or I did something wrong.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activ
ity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.myappActivity}: java.lang.ClassNo
tFoundException: com.mapp.myappActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClass
Loader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.myapp-2.ap
k]
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivi
ty(ActivityThread.java:1667)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(Activi
tyThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Ac
tivityThread.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
07)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6613): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.castva
st.myappActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/co
m.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.myapp-2.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathC
lassLoader.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.j
ava:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.j
ava:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instr
umentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActiv
ity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6613):        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the activity registered in the Manifest?  That error is indicative of a missing Manifest registration - and very common error I might add.  This type of error would not be thrown just by changing the signing cert.

**EDIT**

Check you project properties and make sure your build path includes:

```
system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
```

Comment: Thanks .. but if something is missing in mainfest file ... why it works fine using the unsigned apk?

Comment: Well, actually you always have a signed apk.  Android OS will not run unsigned apks.  When running directly on the emulator, you are actually signing the app with a debug cert.  If you are using Eclipse, then the ADT package for Eclipse signs it for you.  We need to know why the ClassNotFound Exception is happening.  As stated earlier, that's typically an omission in the manifest.  However looking at the error more deeply, it looks like you are not including system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar in your build path.

Comment: Thanks ... it OK, it started to works fine now... i didnt' change any thing, only re-export apk.

Answer (score 1):

The capitalization of this looks weird `com.myapp/com.myapp.myappActivity`

Your class name should start with a capital letter at least: `MyappActivity`

Comment: That's definitely the Java convention.